# How do I give my game a new start in Undertale?

Tags: undertale

I was almost done with the Neutral route, but instead of doing what I was supposed to do, I reset the game. Now Flowey won't appear, and my game keeps resetting when I get to the end. I did not play the Genocide route. What do I do?

Comment: @OrangeDog Actually reading the question would show that's not the case.

Comment: Are you trying to say the game is restarting itself? Or are you just having problems with the True Pacifist ending?

Comment: @Studoku they want to do a full reset, that's what the linked question is also asking

Comment: @OrangeDog Fully resetting the game is different for after the genocide ending and after the normal ending. So no, this is not a dupe.

Comment: @Studoku the same process will fully reset the game at any point. So yes it is a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

If you've killed Flowey, go back to MTT Resort and something should happen:

> You get a call from Undyne, which ultimately leads you to the True Pacifist endings, after which you can do a True Reset, which erases everything.

On the other hand, if you want to reset right away, you're better off reinstalling the game.